# Are complex vector bundles on an Riemann surface admitting flat connections trivial？

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I wonder if the following statement  is true. Or under what kind of condition this could be true?

Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemann surface. $E$ is a complex vector bundle on $M$ admitting a flat connection. Then $M$ is trivial as a complex vector bundle.

All objects above are assumed to be $C^\infty$.

Comment: A complex vector bundle V on a surface is isomorphic to the direct sum of its determinant bundle det(V) and a trivial bundle, and if V has a flat connection so does det(V), i guess, so this reduces the problem to line bundles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand.

Comment: Complex vector bundles over a Riemann surface are topologically classified by their ranks and degrees (the reason was illustrated by the above comment), hence if a complex vector bundle $E$ admitting a flat connection, then all Chern classes vanish, in particular $c_1(E)=0$, hence $E$ is topologically trivial.